# Get all items within ten minutes

Tags: mysql

How would I do the following query:

```
SELECT items FROM table WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL(minutes=10)
```

The syntax of the `NOW() - INTERVAL(...)` is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: something like `timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. You want this.

```
SELECT items 
  FROM table
 WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```